# Trouble Making Grouped Boxplot using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I basically have a dataset with three columns: ER_SIR_100, ER_SIR_50 and MONTH.
And this is the code I use:

```r
error100 <- dataset$ER_SIR_100
error50 <- dataset$ER_SIR_50
month <- dataset$MESN
boxplot(
    error100~month, main='Erro Si_100 x Mês', ylab='Error', xlab='Mês', las=1
)
```

[image: and this is what a got]

The problem is, I wold like to see the boxplots from ER_SIR_100 and ER_SIR_50 side by side, grouped by the month. Is that possible?

Comment: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/265-grouped-boxplot-with-ggplot2.html (the first link listed when I googled the subject of this question).

Comment: actually, at this example you showed, have two categorical variables (variety and treatment) grouped by one continuous variable(note). At my example, I have the opposite. I have two continuous variables (ER_SIR_100 and ER_SIR_50) that i wanted to see side by side grouped by one categorical variable (month)

Comment: It would be relatively trivial if you're able to reshape from wide-to-longer format (e.g., `tidyr::pivot_longer` or `data.table::melt`), as in collapse those two columns into one.

Comment: it worked, thaks!